# If else statement issue

Tags: c

I was wondering say if I entered 3 inputs: 3 1 2 the output gives me  "you've entered in no orderYou've chosen in no order" why is it printing both else statements?

```
int main ()
{

    printf("Please enter 3 integer and will checked if they are in acd or dec: ");
    int x,y,z;
    char trash;
    scanf("%i",&x);
    scanf("%c",&trash);
    scanf("%i",&y);
    scanf("%c",&trash);
    scanf("%i",&z);

    if (x>y&&x>z)
    {
        if (y>z)
        {
            printf("you've entered in decending order ");
        }else{
            printf("you've entered in no order");
        }

    }if (z>x&&z>y)
    {

        if(y>x)
            {
        printf("you've printed in ascending order");
            }
        else
            {printf("you've printed in no order");

        }

    }else{
        printf("You've chosen in no order");
    }
}
```

Comment: Crazy indentation can contribute to misunderstanding how if/else statements nest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the control statements like this

```
if (x>y&&x>z) ...
if (z>x&&z>y) ...
else
```

The `else` corresponds to the second `if` condition, and will execute its body if the condition in the second `if` is false, even if the first condition is true.

I think you mean to do something like this:

```
if (x>y&&x>z) ...
else if (z>x&&z>y) ...
else
```

Comment: Thank you. I was reviewing for an exam and forgot all about it.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement you see, "You've entered in no order," is printed because your input satisfied the test `if (x>y&&x>z)`. Then the second top-level `if` clause is evaluated, and the second statement "You've chosen in on order" is printed because your input does not satisfy `if (z>x&&z>y)`. Both statements are tested because you did not connect them with an `else if`. If you want only one statement to be printed, your top level `if` structure needs to look like this:

```
if (x > y && x > z)
{


} else if (z > x && z > y)
{

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in this line :

```
if (z>x&&z>y)
```

This should be

```
else if (z>x&&z>y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short versión:

```
if (x>y&&y>z){
   printf("you've entered in decending order ");
}else if (z>y&&y>x) {
   printf("you've printed in ascending order");
}else {
   printf("you've printed in no order");
}
```